# Chrome extension: missing class instances in background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a "complex" extension for google chrome, in fact the extension is actually build ([JSLoader](https://github.com/szz-dvl/JSLoader/tree/chrome)), and the structure used in the extension worked a few months ago. Now I want to update it but none of my pop-up's are showing due to some strange behavior of chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(). I have several "modules" declared in  manifest.json as follows:

```
"background": {
        "scripts": [
            "dependencies/dep1.js",
            " ... ",
            "bg/module1.js",
            "bg/module2.js",
            " ... "
            "bg/background.js"
        ]
    },
```

Then in my background page I do instantiate each of the modules the following way:

```
this.module1 = new Module1(this);
this.module2 = new Module2(this);
```

Where module1 and module2 defines the functions (or old style classes) Module1 and Module2 respectively. Then from my pop-up's, concretelly from page action and options page of the extension I'm doing:

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(page => {

    ...
    /* this fails and says that module1 is not defined */ 
    page.module1.callSomeFunctionOnModule1() 
    ...

})
```

As said above this used to work some months ago, and I don't know why my instances are not defined anymore, actually none of the functions defined in the background page are available. Is there any reason I can not do this anymore? What will be the way to call functions on the background from the page actions and option page?

I don't know what to try ... my functions are not defined in the foreground anymore.. I tried to call chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage instead of chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage with no luck.

You can find the complete extension at https://github.com/szz-dvl/JSLoader/tree/chrome

I do expect to be able to access my background functions from my foreground pages (both page action and options page.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work. Start by verifying the current code does work in an older portable Chrome. If it does, you can [bisect the bug](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py) and report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your quick reply, I'm trying to build an older release from chrome, I'm getting the releases from: https://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/old, but everyone of them are giving me unresoluble dependency problems, is there any way i can manage to install an older version of google-chrome in ubuntu or archlinux or any distro? can you point me to the right files? thanks!

Comment: There should be no need to build anything, just find an older package or download an official [Chromium snapshot build](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/) (the revision numbers for a given version can be looked up on [omahaproxy](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com)).

Comment: Thanks! using chromium instead, opening a bug right now, it is working in Chromium 72.0.3626.81. Thanks again!

Comment: New bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945151